# How many pigs can I keep in a single pen at once?

Tags: farm-and-grow

In Farm and Grow, how many pigs can you have in one pen at the same time? I could get one,but I can't seem to be able to buy any more.

Answer (score 1):

Up to four animals of one kind fit in a pen. To get the second one you need to go to market repeatedly until you find a matching pair.

Once there are at least two animals in a pen, new ones will spawn autonomously.

Reference: [source code](https://github.com/stomf/Farm-Grow/blob/master/MarketMenu.as)